# CONTROL_AF_REGIONS of Camera2 is disabled due to the LEGACY level

Tags: java, android, camera, camera2

With AF_MODE set to auto, I first use CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL and capture,
then I set up the AF_REGION to `2486 , 657 : 163 x 122 weight 1000`.

After that, I use CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START and capture again.

But it always focuses on the center of the SurfaceView even I set others values.

Can you show me the sample which AF_REGION is actually working on the Camera2?

I am sorry of my bad English, but i can't find other ways to make the AF_REGION work.

Comment: I tried to make this mess legible. If you want answers, please invest more time in making your posts understandable. An excuse that your English is bad does not help. So, for your next post: Don't use useless abbreviations (e.g. Eng instead of English or u instead of you), use a spellchecker (most browsers include them by now) and try to format your post in a way that is legible. This means, use newlines when useful and use correct punctuation. Questions usually end with question marks (?), not with a semicolon (;).

Comment: check number of focus areas supported. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getMaxNumFocusAreas()